# How to scrape a javascript table with python

Tags: javascript, python, html, datatable

I am trying to scrape the table from this page:
http://data.eastmoney.com/xg/xg/
There are 18 separate pages and the url does not change for each page.

How would I go about trying to scrape this data?
I usually use BeautifulSoup to scrape HTML pages, but in this case the data does not come up in the HTML code, so I cannot use BeautifulSoup on the url to get the data I need.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/). It uses a browser to navigate, therefore executing any JavaScript that may be included.

Comment: Or use your browser's developer tools to find the URL the table data is being loaded from.

Comment: If the data is embedded in the javascript, retrieve the javascript file and find some way of parsing it (pattern matching is the crude way; there may be better ways but it's not something I've done). If the javascript retrieves it from some other source, figure out what URL and parameters it uses (e.g., use the developer console in Chrome to see what network operations occur) and mimic that in Python.

Comment: @That1Guy does Selenium support the chrome browser?

Comment: Yep. [Here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html) is the documentation again.

Answer (score 1):

Well looking at the source of that page it is just making a call to this url which seems to be returning a csv type file you can figure out how to process.

`http://datainterface.eastmoney.com/EM_DataCenter/JS.aspx?type=NS&sty=NSST&st=12&sr=-1&p=1&ps=50&js=var%20IBnVRrwA={pages:%28pc%29,data:[%28x%29]}&stat=1&rt=47876809`

The bottom line is you shouldn't need to scrape this table

Look at the `&ps=50` value this is the limit, put that to something like `&ps=5000` and you shouldn't need to from page to page.

the `&js=var%20IBnVRrwA={pages:%28pc%29,data:[%28x%29]}` bit is the jsonp callback?

Comment: I've looked at using that source code you linked, but if I inspect element in chrome on the table it shows me a nicely formatted HTML data in order. The link you pasted has some of the numbers, but then repeats some and has them out of order, along with tons of empty commas that could be hard to strip

Comment: Take a look at this file. It contains helper  methods, one of them might format the data the way you would like. http://datapic.eastmoney.com/js/load_table_data.js